# Entity associated with non-entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an interface `SupplierInterface` with 2 implementations: `B2BSupplier` (a Doctrine entity), `RetailSupplier` (a static object).

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Model;

interface SupplierInterface {

    const B2B = 'B2B';
    const RETAIL = 'Retail';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSupplierType();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString();
}
```

Another entity, `Supply` has a many-to-one relationship with a `Supplier`. Normally this isn't problematic. But because `RetailSupplier` is not a Doctrine entity, I'm a bit flummoxed about how to proceed.

`Supply` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Blameable\Traits\BlameableEntity;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

/**
 * Supply
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="cir_supply")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Supply
{
    use BlameableEntity;
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B2BSupplier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $supplier; // <-- PROBLEM, since supplier could be B2BSupplier entity, or it could be vanilla object RetailSupplier

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Chemical", inversedBy="supplies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="chemical_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $chemical;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="external_id", type="string")
     */
    protected $externalId;

//getters and setters ...

}
```

How do I specify a Doctrine relationship when that relationship might not always be valid?

Comment: Why does your RetailSupplier have to be a simple object?

Comment: I will give you a few workaround in 15 min or so. You will choose the one that you like better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience I'm 99% sure you can't do what you want in your current setup. That being said, there are a few workarounds I can think of. Also before I go into the workarounds. You should think if you really want OneToOne relation on 'supplier' or will ManyToOne work better. OneToOne has some Lazy loading issues and also Workaround 3 work better with ManyToOne.

**Workaround 1:**

1. Remove the relation and make the supplier filed contain the id, without having a relation defined.
2. Extend SupplierRepository 'find' method to handle the cases where id is
   2.1 'null' there is no relation in witch case it returns RetailSupplier
   2.2 call parent::find for all other cases
   2.3 Optional: if null relations are required change 2.1 to use '0' instead of null (adds con 3)

Pros:

1. fast to achieve from your current setup
2. keep database foreign key (if step 2.3 is ignored)

Cons:

1. hidden behavior of the 'find' method
2. you loose the your doctrine relation
3. not scalable for other types of Suppliers
4. source of the information is split between the app and the database
5. if step 2.3 is required, you loose database foraign key ('0' will not be a foraign key)

---

**Workaround 2:**

1. Modify getSupplier to return RetailSupplier if $this->supplier is null
2. Modify setSupplier to set null if $supplier is instance of RetailSupplyer
3. Optinal:  Change the first 2 steps to handle '0' as RetailSupplyer and 'null' as no relation

Pros:

1. fast to achieve from your current setup
2. keep database foreign key (if step 3 is ignored)
3. keep doctrine relation

Cons:

1. hidden behavior of the setter and getter
2. not scalable for other types of Suppliers
3. if step 3 is required, you loose database foraign key ('0' will not be a foraign key)
4. source of the information is split between the app and the database

---

**Workaround 3** (doctrine inheritance mapping):

1. Create an abstract (called Supplier) this will be inherited by RetailSupplyer and B2BSupplier
2. Add inheritance metadata to Supplier abstract something like this
3. Create an entity for RetailSupplyer and a database table with one single line to start (the first RetailSupplier)
4. Change your database to match your inheritance mapping settings (for more info http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)
5. Change your relation to ManyToOne on $supplier and make it to point to Supplier

Pros:

1. source of the information is only the database
2. no hidden behavior in your code
3. scalable for other types of suppliers and other more retail suppliers

Cons:

1. harder to achieve from your current setup (database changes, new doctrine setup, possibly some refactor)

pros/cons: Depending on the selected inheritance type you can have full relation path in your database (with foraign key), or you can have no relations. This is up to you ;) after you read the documentation for inheritance mapping.

---

PS: If I had to choose i will go with Workaround 3. It is hardest to achieve, but solid do it.

Hope this helps and happy coding

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: Thank you for outlining the options so succinctly! I've been gravitating towards Workaround 3 for some time. But I was also considering some sort of `SupplierProvider` that could handle a variety of different data sources, Doctrine and config files included. But that would probably be overkill. (p.s. I agree, the `OneToOne` definitely should have been `ManyToOne`. Don't know how that slipped by!)

Comment: Glad I was able to help.I wish there was also an option to extend EntityManager/UnitOfWork of doctrine. That could have also been a solution for your problem, and for some other issues like having a relation with a RESTful API. But unfortunately for us (and fortunately for the ppl working on doctrine) most of doctrine code respect the SOLID principles, overzealous in some cases even, making it hard to extend part of the system. Anyway, happy coding and gl with your project.